# Unable to select element from drop down using Actions class in webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to select an element from drop down. I have no option to use Select class and I am trying to use Actions class. It only locates the drop down but does not select the element in the drop down as it cannot identify the xpath. The xpath appears to be correct but still is not getting accepted. Below is the HTML dev tools and the code in java.

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNakg.png):

```html
<a id="6008" name="mItem" nowrap="true" class="itemStyle" style="color: black; background-color: rgb(238, 243, 251); cursor: default;"><div class="arrow-right"></div>Financial Planning</a>
<a id="1693" name="mItem" nowrap="true" class="itemStyle" style="color: black; background-color: rgb(238, 243, 251); cursor: default;"><div class="arrow-right"></div>Assets/Revenue</a>
<a id="30241" name="mItem" nowrap="true" class="itemStyle" style="cursor: pointer; color: white; background-color: rgb(127, 158, 195);">FA Productivity</a>
```

Java Code:

```java
WebElement wb = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='1692']"));
Thread.sleep(2000);
Actions mouse = new Actions(webDriver);
mouse.moveToElement(wb).click();
WebElement wb2 = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='30241']"));
Thread.sleep(2000);
mouse.moveToElement(wb2).click();
mouse.build(); 
mouse.perform();
```

Comment: <a id="30241" name="mItem" nowrap="true" class="itemStyle" style="cursor: pointer; color: white; background-color: rgb(127, 158, 195);">FA Productivity</a>

Comment: display:none style is set on the div... that'll be an issue.  Do whatever actions you need to display it first.  Then just use wb2.click()... you might also want to use webdriverwaits with expected conditions here.  (To wait for items to be clickable/visible/etc...)

Comment: Based on HTML and Screen shot you have attached , id is 1693 the why you are using 1692 ? Also can you clarify what exactly you want ? Like which tag is your drop down and which one is the value you want to select inside it ?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to just select the element, you can use javascript click which will click the element as long as it is present in DOM unlike the regular selenium click which needs the element to be displayed
`Driver.get().executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`

Comment: The above code didn't work as it could not click on the dropdown element. However I used the below code which made the test pass. However its not opening the page after selecting the dropdown option. It just closes the application--->                                          
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
        js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('1692').selectedIndex = '" + 3 + "'");

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code.

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath(""));
for(WebElement option : options) {
   if (option.getText().contains("FA Productivity")) {
     option.click();
     break;
   }
 }
```

If possible please share the test URL, so that I can replicate your scenario.

Comment: With your code snippet also its passing the test, however its not opening the screen :FA Productivity". I dont see the drop down getting clicked and this option selected as well. It simply terminates the test without opening the screen and passes the test.I have shared the HTML code in page above.